# How to return the name with maximum score in sql (Oracle 11g)?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this table in an Oracle 11g database:

```
Id Name Score
-------------
1   A     1
2   A     2
3   A     3
4   B     2
5   B     1
```

And I need to prepare a query which returns the rows of each name (A and B) with the max score. In this example it would be:

```
Id Name Score
-------------
3   A     3
4   B     2
```

How can I do this in Oracle 11g (I think that I cannot use LIMIT 1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
with data as(
    select 1 id, 'A' name, 1 score from dual union all
    select 2 id, 'A' name, 2 score from dual union all
    select 3 id, 'A' name, 3 score from dual union all
    select 4 id, 'B' name, 2 score from dual union all
select 5 id, 'B' name, 1 score from dual
)
select id, name, score from(
  select id, name, score, row_number() over(partition by name order by score desc) rn
  from data
) where rn = 1;

ID NAME SCORE
-- ---- -----
 3 A        3
 4 B        2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by`:

```
select name, max(score),
       max(id) keep (dense_rank first order by score desc) as id
from t
group by name;
```

The `keep` expression is Oracle's way of saying "first".

Comment: It works well, but I also need the ID in the result of the query :) And If I add Id in the select it shows repeated rows

Comment: @Adrian . . . This HAS the id in the query result.  It even explains how it is calculated.  Did you try the query?

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_umber()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by score desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```